# Exit loop if while condition is met

Tags: c#, do-while

I have a program that stores user input in an array.
Every time a user input is stored, the int var Counter is increased by 1.
My problem is that if i store 25 variables, the loop ends BUT lets say i enter something that is not valid, the loop continues even after the 25 variables are stored. I want to make sure that the loop ends after the while condition is met even if the program catches the error if that makes any sense.

And no, i want to use an array and not a list!

Thanks

```
        void AddPassenger()
    {
        //Counts total passengers on the bus to determin if the buss is empty
        Passenger.TotalPassengers = 0;

        //Variable for loops
        int Counter = 0;

        do
        {
            //Adds 25 passengers with a loop
            for (int i = 0; i < Passenger.Age.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Logo();
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Age for passenger {0}", Counter + 1);
                Counter++;

                try
                {
                    Passenger.Age[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Did you enter a number?\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to try again...");
                    Counter--;
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                }
                //Checks if user enters a valid age
                if (Passenger.Age[i] < 0 || Passenger.Age[i] > 130)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Try a different age");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Gender for passenger {0}", Counter);
                Console.WriteLine("1) Male");
                Console.WriteLine("2) Female");
                Console.WriteLine("3) Other");

                //Using a temp variable to run switch for selecting gender
                int temp = 0;

                try
                {
                    temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Clear();
                    Passenger.TotalPassengers++;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Logo();
                    Console.WriteLine("\nNot a valid choice");
                }

                switch (temp)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Passenger.Gender[i] = "Male";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Passenger.Gender[i] = "Female";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Passenger.Gender[i] = "Other";
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Did you enter a number?\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to try again...");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Counter--;
                        break;
                }
            }

        } while (Counter < 25);
```

[image: This is not suppose to happen]

This is not suppose to happen

Comment: You keep incrementing `i` even if the input is invalid. If you want to restart the inner loop logic after a user error is detected (without incrementing `i`), use `continue;`.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError where should i put `continue;` ?

Comment: Right after `Counter--`. Speaking of which, it would probably be cleaner to not touch `Counter` until you have verified all input, that way you'll only adjust it that one time.

Comment: See [int.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0). Much more efficient than try/catch.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError When `continue;` is there it keeps on going longer than without `continue;` hmm

Comment: You should not need two loops.

Comment: @jwdonahue So remove the while loop?

Comment: Hard to say. You didn't post an [mcve], but I don't see the purpose of the two loops.

Comment: Issue is the `do while` loop is probably the most appropriate one here but you're using the for loop as the indexer for the array. I would personally remove the `for` loop and use the `Counter` value as the indexer. Move the 25 value for max passengers out into a `const` and use that variable in the capacity of the `Array` values as well as the `while` expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 loops here, a for loop and a do-while loop. The for loop only stops if `i` reaches the array's limit, and the do-while loop only stops if `Counter` reaches 25.

You mentioned the loop continues even after 25 variables are stored. This is because the for loop restarts at 0 every time there's invalid input. Swap `int i = 0` out for `int i = Counter`, that way, it continues where it left off.

Additionally:

You don't need 2 loops, specifically the for loop. You can remove it then replace all mentions of `i` with `Counter`, the same for `break` with `continue`. (In combination with @Tubs' answer)You also won't need `if(Counter >= 25) break;` in this case. Doing that effectively merges the 2 loops, instead of having 2 loops with the same function.

`Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Gender for passenger {0}", Counter);` doesn't add 1 to `Counter`, which will result in `Enter Gender for passenger 0`.

Extending on @Tubs' answer:
Also, Counter is only incremented after all the `break`s, which means it's unreachable. You'll have to transfer to each successful case(1, 2, and 3).
The resulting code is:

```cs
        void AddPassenger()
    {
        //Counts total passengers on the bus to determin if the buss is empty
        Passenger.TotalPassengers = 0;

        //Variable for loops
        int Counter = 0;

        //Adds 25 passengers with a loop
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Logo();
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Age for passenger {0}", Counter + 1);

            try
            {
                Passenger.Age[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Did you enter a number?\n");
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to try again...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                continue;
                // Continue while loop instead of breaking it
            }
            //Checks if user enters a valid age
            if (Passenger.Age[i] < 0 || Passenger.Age[i] > 130)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try a different age");
                continue;
                // Continue while loop instead of breaking it
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Gender for passenger {0}", Counter + 1);
            Console.WriteLine("1) Male");
            Console.WriteLine("2) Female");
            Console.WriteLine("3) Other");

            //Using a temp variable to run switch for selecting gender
            int temp = 0;

            try
            {
                temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Clear();
                Passenger.TotalPassengers++;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Logo();
                Console.WriteLine("\nNot a valid choice");
                continue;
                // Continue while loop instead of breaking it
            }

            switch (temp)
            {
                case 1:
                    Passenger.Gender[i] = "Male";
                    // Increment after success
                    Counter++;
                    continue;
                    // Continue while loop instead of breaking it
                case 2:
                    Passenger.Gender[i] = "Female";
                    // Increment after success
                    Counter++;
                    continue;
                    // Continue while loop instead of breaking it
                case 3:
                    Passenger.Gender[i] = "Other";
                    // Increment after success
                    Counter++;
                    continue;
                    // Continue while loop instead of breaking it
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Did you enter a number?\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to try again...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    continue;
                    // Continue while loop instead of breaking it
            }

        } while (Counter < 25);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the scope of your question you could do something similar to the following (note this has not been run but quickly knocked up with comments)

```cs
void AddPassenger()
    {
        //Counts total passengers on the bus to determin if the buss is empty
        Passenger.TotalPassengers = 0;

        //Variable for loops
        int Counter = 0;

        do
        {
            //Adds 25 passengers with a loop
            for (int i = 0; i < Passenger.Age.Length; i++)
            {
                // ensure we're not leaving the scope of the `while`
                if(Counter >= 25)
                    break;
                Console.Clear();
                Logo();
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Age for passenger {0}", Counter + 1);
                
                try
                {
                    Passenger.Age[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Did you enter a number?\n");
                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to try again...");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                }
                
                //Checks if user enters a valid age
                if (Passenger.Age[i] < 0 || Passenger.Age[i] > 130)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Try a different age");
                    break; // you needed to break here I assume
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter Gender for passenger {0}", Counter);
                Console.WriteLine("1) Male");
                Console.WriteLine("2) Female");
                Console.WriteLine("3) Other");

                //Using a temp variable to run switch for selecting gender
                int temp = 0;

                try
                {
                    temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Clear();
                    Passenger.TotalPassengers++;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                    Logo();
                    Console.WriteLine("\nNot a valid choice");
                    break; // you needed to break here I assume
                }

                switch (temp)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Passenger.Gender[i] = "Male";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Passenger.Gender[i] = "Female";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Passenger.Gender[i] = "Other";
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Did you enter a number?\n");
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to try again...");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;
                }
                Counter++; //move counter to here to only increment at the end if successful
            }

        } while (Counter < 25);
```

However, I would either change the name for `Passenger` or the model itself as it isn't clear why Passenger has an Array of ages or genders. Surely each passenger should be its own entity with these fields no?

Something like:

```cs
public Bus
{
    public Passenger[] Passengers { get; set; }
    public int TotalPassengers { get; set; }
}

public Passenger
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

The `for` loop inside the while should be re-thought about. It doesn't make sense for a nested loop in this way.

Comment: Thanks for that. The loop now works. I will look into the for loop. I have a class called Passenger. Will the `{ get; set; }` work in similar way to what i use now? The TotalPassengers variable is in the Passenger class as well

Comment: Yes you're simply specifying the accessors